# 401 unauthorized when using spring security BCrypt in Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, bcrypt

I'm trying to implement **Bcrypt** to hash passwords. But the issue I'm facing is that Spring Security enables authentication for all end points by default. But I don't want that I just want to signup a user and simply generate hash for the passwords. But I can't do that as when I make a **Post** request from Postman it shows **401 Unauthorized**.4

**I tried the following things in main class:**

**1-**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
```

**2-**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

**3-**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

**4-**

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(); 
        return http.build();
    }
```

**5-**

**I tried with `org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4` but when I try to use `BCrypt` in my service function it does not import it from `mindrot`**

**I want to use spring security for Authentication and Authorization in future, But First I need to sign up a user and hash his password.**

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '19'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.mindrot:jbcrypt:0.4'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**main class**

```
package com.example.bcrypt;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class BcryptApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BcryptApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**UserRepo**

```
package com.example.bcrypt.repository.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.bcrypt.entity.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>{
    
}
```

**UserService**

```
package com.example.bcrypt.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.bcrypt.entity.User;
import com.example.bcrypt.repository.dao.UserRepository;


@Service
public class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    public User create(User body){

        BCryptPasswordEncoder bcrypt=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        String hashedpassword=bcrypt.encode(body.getPassword());

        body.setPassword(hashedpassword);

        User res=userRepo.save(body);

        System.out.println(res);

        return res;
    }
    
}
```

**UserControlelr**

```
package com.example.bcrypt.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.bcrypt.entity.User;
import com.example.bcrypt.service.UserService;

@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public User create(@RequestBody User body){
        User res=userService.create(body);

        System.out.println(res);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know `bcryptencoder` is ok. But What to do with that `401` I can't make any request due to spring security...

Comment: But why do you need the mindrot bcrypt encoder, you can use the one that's in spring. To have a registration endpoint, you'll have to configure spring security to allow requests without password, that's what the roughly `.antmatcher("/register").permitAll()` code does here: https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration/blob/master/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/SecSecurityConfig.java#L80 (source from the linked example above)

Comment: With `@EnableWebSecurity` and `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.baeldung.security" })` and With This `@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .antMatchers("/registration*")
            .permitAll();
   return http.build();
 }` I'm getting `The method antMatchers(String) is undefined for the HttpSecurity`.

Comment: Btw I'm doing it in main class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request fails because of spring security. You can add exceptions or disable it completely by providing a simple `@Bean`.

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
  return http
    .csrf()
    .disable()
    .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> authorizeExchangeSpec.anyExchange().permitAll())
    .build();
}
```

I count'tell from your code what endpoint you're calling so in the example above I've allowed any request. Note that you should not do that in production environments.

Edit:

I'm sorry, I gave you a bean for webflux.

You should be able to use this bean instead and have it all working.
I usually create a configuration class ex:

SecurityConfig.java

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.cors().disable()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/users/register").permitAll().and()
                .build();
    }
}
```